# How to continous count by using SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
 Regarding my table as below
```

WORKING_CALENDAR_TABLE

```
===================================================
 EMPLOYEE ID    |        DATE        | WORKING DAY (0: Holiday; 1: WORKING DAY)
===================================================
  02661              2017/12/01            1
  02661              2017/12/02            1
  02661              2017/12/03            0
  02661              2017/12/04            0
  02661              2017/12/05            0
  02661              2017/12/06            1
  02661              2017/12/07            1
  02661              2017/12/08            1
  02661              2017/12/09            1
```

When 2017/12/10, my expected result as below

```
===================================================
 EMPLOYEE ID    | CONTINOUS WORKING DAY 
===================================================
   02661                   4
```

IF WE USE SQL ORACLE, CAN WE UTILIZE SQL ORACLE to got this result ?

Comment: Please show SQL that you tried in order to get the results that you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it can be by:

1. Getting the last day before your reference date (`2017/12/10`) where the employee didn´t work.
2. Counting the rows after the date in 1. and before your reference date. Forcibly, each row represents a working day for the employee.

Here's the code with some comments:

```
Select employee_id, count(*) as continuous_days  from mytable 
where employee_id = '02661'  and date > (select max(date) 
where employee_id ='02661' and working_day = 0 and date date < 
'2017/12/10') and date < 
'2017/12/10' group by employee_id

 /* (select max(date) 
where employee_id ='02661' and working_day = 0 and date < 
'2017/12/10') gets the last day where the employee didn't work before the reference date. Each row from a date after max(date) represent a working day for the employee because all of them are going to to have working_day = 1*/
```

**Something to improve here:**
In the case the employee had no holidays before a reference date then 
   `select max(date) 
    where employee_id ='02661' and working_day = 0 and date date < 
    '2017/12/10'` will return `null` so you could use `COALESCE` to prevent errors and in the case of a null, you get some other value in return. I think that in your case it would suffice with a very early date. You could use it this way:

`COALESCE( (select max(date) 
where employee_id ='02661' and working_day = 0 and date < 
'2017/12/10'),  '1900-01-01')`

and the complete query would be:

```
select employee_id, count(*) as continuous_days  from mytable 
where employee_id = '02661'  and date > COALESCE( (select max(date) 
where employee_id ='02661' and working_day = 0 and date < 
'2017/12/10'),  '1900-01-01') and date < 
'2017/12/10' group by employee_id
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the original problem, some explanation would greatly improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: I'm sorry @Nigel. I was in a hurry when I wrote it. I'm editing it in a minute

Answer (score 0):

For a given date, the most general solution is:

```
select employee_id, count(*)
from t
where employee_id = '02661' and
      date < date '2017-12-10' and
      date > (select max(t2.date)
              from t t2
              where t2.employee_id = t.employee_id and t2.date < date '2017-12-10'
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT T.EMPLOYEE_ID,
       COUNT(0) AS CONTINUOUS_DAYS
FROM   WORKING_CALENDAR_TABLE T
WHERE  T.WORK_DATE BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(WORK_DATE) + 1
                            FROM   WORKING_CALENDAR_TABLE I
                            WHERE  I.EMPLOYEE_ID = T.EMPLOYEE_ID
                                   AND I.WORK_DAY = 0)
                            AND DATE '2017-12-10' + 1
GROUP  BY T.EMPLOYEE_ID
```